# How to load JavaScript conditionally

Tags: javascript, razor

Is there any way to conditionally load JavaScript reference files in ASP.Net Razor View? There are 15 web pages in my project. They refer to common set of libraries say A, B, C, D. However, there is one page which require library E instead of B.

How can I write the  tags so that it will load library E only for that particular page? And also it will NOT LOAD B for the same page?

If I load E and B both, then the page crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set some flag, such as

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Script = "B";
    return View();
}
```

and on your view

```
if ((ViewBag.Script as string) == "B")
{
}
else
{
}
```

---

You can use @section, but then you couldn't include all scripts on the _Layout

[image: render on layout view]

[image: section on view]

[ASP.NET MVC 3: Layouts and Sections with Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx)

Comment: Thanks BrunoLM! The first option looks easier. Let me give it a try.